# Custom spritecollide hitboxes

Tags: python, pygame

So I am trying to see if there are any collisions between a `sprite` and any object in a specific group. I used `sprite.spritecollide` as this is what this pygame method does, but I want to use custom `hitboxes` for the objects rather than their `.rect` `hitboxes`.

```
def collide_hit_rect(one, two):
    return one.hit_rect.colliderect(two.rect)

def collide_hit_rect_two(one, two):
    return one.hit_rect.colliderect(two.hit_rect)

class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.image = game.player_img
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.hit_rect = PLAYER_HIT_RECT
        self.hit_rect.center = self.rect.center
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.pos = vec(x+0.5, y+0.5) * TILESIZE
        self.rot = 0

class Door(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y, side):
        rotation = ['R', 'U', 'L', 'D']
        self.groups = game.all_sprites, game.doors
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)
        self.game = game
        self.side = side
        angle = rotation.index(self.side)*90
        self.image = game.door_img
        self.image = pg.transform.rotate(self.image, angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        if side == rotation[0]:
            self.hit_rect = pg.Rect(36, 0, 28, 64)
        elif side == rotation[1]:
            self.hit_rect = pg.Rect(0, 0, 64, 28)
        elif side == rotation[2]:
            self.hit_rect = pg.Rect(0, 0, 28, 64)
        elif side == rotation[3]:
            self.hit_rect = pg.Rect(0, 36, 64, 28)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect.x = self.x * TILESIZE
        self.rect.y = self.y * TILESIZE
```

Now, when I want to check for collisions between a player and an object's `rect`, I can use collide
`_hit_rect()`, and it correctly uses the `sprite`'s `.hit_rect` and object's `.rect` instead of `.rect` for both, e.g.

```
hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(sprite, group, False, collide_hit_rect)
```

However, when wanting to check for collisions between the door and player using both their `.hit_rect` rather than `.rect`, this doesn't work and it never recognises collisions.

```
hits = pg.sprite.spritecollide(sprite, group, False, collide_hit_rect_two)
```

Is there something wrong with my door class and its `hitbox` or what else could it possibly be?

Comment: The position of `self.rect` is set at the end of the constructor of `Door`, but `self.hit_rect` always is around (0, 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position of `self.rect` is set at the end of the constructor of Door:

> ```
> self.rect.x = self.x * TILESIZE
> self.rect.y = self.y * TILESIZE
> ```

but the position of `self.hit_rect` is never set and is always around (0, 0). Set the location of `self.hit_rect`, the same way as you do it with `self.rect`:

```
self.hit_rect.x = self.x * TILESIZE
self.hit_rect.y = self.y * TILESIZE
```